# Weapon proficiency training and penalties in 4th ed

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

I know that proficiency can be acquired trough picking class or selecting a feat. But I cant seem to find a feat that would give training in superior melee. Do I need to pick a feat for only one type of weapon? Also, what are the penalties for using weapon you don't have proficiency for and are these penalties reduced if PC has training in similar weapons? For example, use of of military melee weapons while have training only in simple.

Reason for this question is that I want to give a human Warlord a waraxe for that 1d12. For some reason char builder shows that I do have +2 proficiency for it all trough warlord proficiency list doesn't have superior melee listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *is* a weapon proficiency feat; it grants you proficiency with any one weapon of your choice, regardless of what kind of weapon (simple/martial/superior) the weapon is.

If you use a weapon you are not proficient with then you do not receive its proficiency bonus to attack rolls (the character builder is buggy about this and will often show you receiving it, but the rules clearly state that you don't get the bonus if you're not proficient). Nothing reduces this penalty; you could be proficient with every single weapon except one, and you would still not get the bonus for that one weapon.